# loading the doctrine fixtures

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to generate fixtures by using the command:

```
php app/console generate:fixtures:load
```

it gives me this error:

```
The autoloader expected class "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\Doctrine
FixturesBundle" to be defined in file "C:\wamp\www\SymfonyV1\app/../vendor/Bundl
es\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle.php". The file
was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has
a typo.
```

I checked tha class is there.

Do you know how to fix this please??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this is connected to the DoctrineFixtures bundle being moved from Symfony to Doctrine on github. It cause me a bit of confusion when I updated to 2.0.15.

The DoctrineFixturesBundle.php file should be located in vendors/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle/ and have the namespace Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle.

Answer (score 1):

You must move your bundle into

```
App\vendor\bundles\Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Doctrine
```

and declare it your appKernel :

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
```

This change is due to doctrine2  who moved from Symfony folder to Doctrine

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. Do you forget add proper namespace declaration to your class file?